# Why is my password not working in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help. I am trying to log on minecraft, but it is not working.
I log on minecraft everyday, but still it is not working. 
Could someone please tell what is happening? :)

Comment: You should probably contact Mojang customer support for that. https://help.mojang.com/

Comment: I think you would get help faster if you contact [Mojang support](https://help.mojang.com/) directly.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, you can always accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' on the question above. Doing so will allow the community to know that my answer worked for you so that if they were to face the same problem, they may react accordingly. In addition, both of us will receive some reputation points. A WIN-WIN! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unable to connect with your current password, try the following:

1. **Try [resetting](https://minecraft.net/resetpassword) you password**

   - An e-mail would then be sent to the email address you have included
     when you first created you Minecraft account
2. **Are you using a Minecraft account or a Mojang account?**

   - If you are using a Mojang account, go to [this site](https://account.mojang.com/resetpassword/request) to reset your
     password
3. **Lastly, and most importantly, Mojang had to do [some maintenance recently](https://help.mojang.com/). This might be the reason why you were unable to log in.**

> Due to an exploit in the OpenSSL software we were forced to temporary
>   suspend all of our services. All systems are now back online, and the
>   exploit has been fixed. We can not guarantee that your information
>   wasn't compromised. Therefore we recommend everyone to change their
>   Mojang/Minecraft account passwords.

They also mentioned that they cannot guarantee that all accounts have not been compromised. So I advise you to change your password if you can ASAP!

Comment: Thank you again David Toh! It worked. You are the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify your caps lock is not on.

Also you should really contact Mojang as they can help you a lot better than this community can.